# Crayfish plugin doesn't work in QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attributeerror

I have installed QGIS 3.20 in my computer and wanted to use crayfish plugin for Mesh analysis. When I install the plugin it shows the following error and the plugin does not appearing in the toolbox window.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'crayfish' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\crayfish\gui\plot_widget.py", line 38, in 
    import pyqtgraph
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'
```

Comment: Did you have before another QGIS version on your PC? You can try installing the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, maybe it can resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes I have a QGIS Version 3.16.4

Comment: I did install request, but it doest work either.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned in an issue back in February:

https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-crayfish-plugin/issues/478

looks like it needs a newer pyqtgraph module.